# Merging questions affecting answers

Tags: discussion

If you wanted to edit a question by merging it with another, is the best you can do to mark it as a duplicate? Can you move the answers to the first question, then delete the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, marking as a duplicate is the only option.  It works well enough in the other communities, so it should be fine.

If the question doesn't have any answers yet, the original poster can delete it once it's been marked as a duplicate, which is what should usually happen. Before answering a question, it's best to check for duplicates for this reason.